# How to return List of JSON data from Spring mVC

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I want to return the data which itself is JSON data, but looks like Spring HttpMessageConverters again converting the data to JSON and finally giving me data with escape characters around all double quotes.

Below is my controller code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/getSummary"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST},        produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public List<String> getSummary(@RequestBody long empId) {

}
```

In the response i am getting JSON but with escape characters like below:

```
{
   "nameSummary": "{ \"_id\" : 3242242 , \"name\" : \"juan\"}",
   "addressSummary": "{ \"_id\" : 3242243 , \"name\" : \"john\"}",
   "bioSummary": "{ \"_id\" : 3242244 , \"name\" : \"eric\"}"
}
```

I tried various ways like @JsonRawValue, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE , but not working.

I want the output without escape characters, Could you please do the needful help please.

UPDATE: I tried even with a POJO which contains 3 fileds, where each field will contain JSON data, still same issue.

Thanks & Regards
Venkat

Comment: is one entry in the list a json string? example? "nameSummary": "{ \"_id\" : 3242242 , \"name\" : \"juan\"}". if so you could write the response your self or make a bean example Summery and let spring convert it completly to json.

Comment: Thank you Hank. In above example i gave 2 fields, actually i have 100+ fields, so preparing a bean is difficult. With Bean, its working fine. Spring converted bean to json. But i want to send the json data directly.

Comment: Can i achieve this by using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver or having a customized version of HttpMessageConverters may be StringHttpMessageConverter, MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter

Answer (score 0):

Sending JSON Data directly

```
//request mapping
public void getSummary(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody long empId) {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
      respone.getwriter().write(myjson);
      response.getWriter().flush();
      response.close();
}
```

I ommited error handling and the other stuff.

This was the way to do it before @REsponseBody was an option.

Comment: in this case you are complete responsable to create the json.

Comment: Thank you Hank, The solution you provided will work 100% and i think we don't need to do flush and close explicitly if i am correct. If we could not able to achieve this with any other solution, definitely will go with this solution only.

Comment: my code is only srawled. It only should point you in direction. If my answer is ok, please mark it as answered :-)

Comment: Totally Agree Hank :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make the use of google's **Gson**

> Gson is a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into
>   their JSON representation. It can also be used to convert a JSON
>   string to an equivalent Java object

Sample code for how to use Gson

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<String>>() {}.getType();
 List<String> target = new LinkedList<String>();
 target.add("blah");

 Gson gson = new Gson();
 String json = gson.toJson(target, listType);
 List<String> target2 = gson.fromJson(json, listType);
```